# Exchange Key in a Python Dict File if Value in the Dict equals 1 and then counting them up to new Key

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

I have a Dict file that looks like this:

```
"asks": 2,
"Hey": 1,
"I": 2,
"Jim": 3,
"Like": 4,
"Love": 1,
"she": 1,
"You": 2
```

I want to manipulate the Keys of the Values that == 1 to "False" and then add them up to a new value. So my Final Dict should look like this:

```
"asks": 2,
"False": 3,
"I": 2,
"Jim": 3,
"Like": 4,
"You": 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
d = {"asks": 2, "Hey": 1, "I": 2, "Jim": 3, "Like": 4, "Love": 1, "she": 1, "You": 2}

res = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    if value == 1:
        res["False"] = res.get("False", 0) + value
    else:
        res[key] = value
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'asks': 2, 'False': 3, 'I': 2, 'Jim': 3, 'Like': 4, 'You': 2}
```

Or using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
res = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in d.items():
    if value == 1:
        res["False"] += value
    else:
        res[key] = value
print(res)
```